# Linux (Manjaro, xfce) Ctrl-w is not working (user wide)

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, manjaro

I have a very annoying issue: Ctrl-W (both: Left-Ctrl-W and Right-Ctrl-W) is not working in **ALL** applications (Chromium, Firefox, Mousepad etc). So it is not a application issue.

- Manjaro Linux
- Kernel 5.10.102
- xfce 4.16
- Window-Manager => Keyboard: no entry with Ctrl-W
- Settings => Keyboard => Applications Shortcuts: no entry with Ctrl-W
- other shortcuts as Ctrl-S are working fine
- `sudo showkey -s` show this: `0x1d 0x11 0x91 0x9d`
- I did try to use an other keyboard: Ctrl-W is not working
- this issue is limited to my user. When I open a new user on Manjaro (`sudo useradd -m test`) on this test-user: Ctrl-W is working

Are there other configs? If you need config-files, let me know.

---

**SOLUTION (for this case)**

xfce => Settings Manager => Keyboard => Application Shortcuts => [Reset to Defaults]

The issue was, that I had a custom command with the shortcut `Ctrl-§`. This shortcut kills Ctrl-W! After changing to `Super-§` Ctrl-W is working again.

Comment: See if this helps  .....  https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ctrl-keys-not-working-properly/54986/4     Another link at the bottom.   I have xfce on Kali here and no issue with Ctrl-W (left or right).

Comment: John, thank you for your link. Unfortunately it does not help. Other shortcuts as Ctrl-S are working fine.

Comment: I am not sure what else - are you sure Manjaro is compatible with xfce?   Was Wayland installed?  It needs to be uninstalled first.

Comment: John, yes, Manjaro is compatible with xfce (see https://manjaro.org/download). Wayland is installed (packages ```wayland``` and ```wayland-protocols```. But my session is running under X11 (```loginctl show-session 2 -p Type```). Why should be problem, when wayland is installed?

Comment: Wayland should be uninstalled and Gnome as well if it was installed. It was going to be an undertaking to prepare Ubuntu for xfce and I put the idea down.

Comment: John, thank you again for your effort! A friend of me suggested me to use that under an other manjaro user and Ctrl-W is working under this new user. So i assume it is not an issue with Wayland / Gnome, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to solve by this:

- xfce => Settings Manager => Keyboard => Application Shortcuts => [Reset to Defaults]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I have posted an issue hopefully it will get fixed :)

https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/-/issues/442

Comment: Thank you harre! I didnt know how to report this to xfce but you have done it. BTW: the issue was on Swiss-German keyboard.